# Error in javascript to include an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

I'm doing a rails project where I make use of pageless jquery plugin https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js 
In his script he has written to take an image file:

```
var settings = {
    container: window,
    currentPage: 0,
    distance: 100,
    pagination: '.pagination',
    params: {},
    url: location.href,
    loaderImage: "images/load.gif",
    method: 'get'
};
```

I've placed my image in app/assets/images folder, yet when I run my project in a browser the image doesnt load up and gives out a:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/images/load.gif"
```

What is wrong with the path? Doesn't it make use of the Assets pipeline?

Comment: where is the file located that have this code?

Comment: Its the javascipt code in app/assets/javascript/jquery.pageless.js

Comment: @Raghuveer: what is the image location?

Comment: Have you tested in a browser whether there is any `http://localhost:3000/images/load.gif` ?? It just seems as bad written path :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your page is in the root and it searches the images in folder in `root(app)`.

Better try changing

```
  loaderImage: "images/load.gif",
```

to

```
  loaderImage: "assets/images/load.gif",
```

Comment: @Raghuveer, did you clear the cache(Ctrl+f5) and run?

Comment: @Raghuveer, try `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/load.gif` directly in the browser url, and see whether it loads the image

Comment: Yes. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Gave the url directly in the browser but then 'No such route matches' pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Put a slash infront of assets like this loaderImage: " app/assets/images/load.gif"  or " /app/assets/images/load.gif"

Comment: Tried again. Not working. This is really getting into me now. Can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
loaderImage: "assets/load.gif"
```

works fine.